# Need help converting a piece of a JSON response into a DateTime

Tags: c#, json, format, response

I'm making an azure function that is taking data from a remote API and placing the information in a local database.

Everything has been going great, except the way the API has the date formatted is giving me trouble.

In the response, dates are formatted like this:

`... "registrationDate": "24-Mar-2020 UTC", ...`

If I use any regular method of converting the response into my model I get a "System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'"

I've tried using my own custom formatting... but have had no success.
One of the formats I tried was: "yyyy - MMM - dd' UTC'" (I did so very unconfidently).

My guess is my lack of knowledge when it comes to formatting is what is my issue. Could anyone help me with this? THANK YOU

Comment: try `dd-MMM-yyyy UTC`

Comment: Hmmm, tried that but nothing. Any other ideas?

Comment: yes, share the relevant code. With `InvariantCulture`, that format works.

Comment: It appears dd-MMM-yyyy UTC was correct, it's just the 18th response has a wacky value that is throwing the exception. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please try DateTime.ParseExact:

```
        string dateString = "24-Mar-2020 UTC";
        DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd-MMM-yyyy UTC", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```